# Firestore not returning query Swift 5 Xcode 11.3

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to develop an ios application using Firestore, and when querying the database, I'm getting no results, as neither the if/else block execute. I'm wondering what is going wrong here...

```
db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error getting documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            weight = document.data()["weight"]! as? Double
        }
    }
}
```

[Database file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WanE.png)

**Update:** I make a call to the database in an earlier method, and this properly returns the user's first name (when I add the weight, it also returns the correct value). But any subsequent calls fail to return anything. Hopefully that info helps.

Comment: on the previous consult, do you retrieve the same fields?

Comment: Different fields

Comment: Please don't put links in your question. Links tend to break over time and that would invalidate the question. Include the image *in* the question.

Comment: Why are you doing this? The users UID is the documentID so you don't need to query for it, just read it directly. `db.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument(`

Comment: do you have rules?, please check the following document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Firestore structure like you, and this works for me:

```
func test() {
    var accessLevel: Double?
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_UID!).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                accessLevel = document.data()["accessLevel"]! as? Double
                print(accessLevel!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current uid:

```
// Actual logged-in User
var CURRENT_USER_UID: String? {
    if let currentUserUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        return currentUserUid
    }
    return nil
}
```

Hope it helps.